# Terratest Azure how to use -auto-approve -input=false

Tags: azure, terraform, terratest

Thank you for the great work at terratest.

I am using terratest to test Azure deployments.

This is the command I have to apply the terraform and I am trying to achieve the same thing from terratest

```
terraform apply -no-color -auto-approve -input=false -var-file "../environments/env/shared.tfvars" -var-file "../environments/env/cont_reg.tfvars"
```

And here is my code from sample_test.go:

```
    terraformOptions := &terraform.Options{
        TerraformDir: "../scripts",
        NoColor: true,
        BackendConfig: map[string]interface{}{
            "storage_account_name": storageactname,
            "key": fname,
        },
```

How can I achieve the **-auto-approve** and **-input=false** part from the terratest apply?
Note: I am able to use `-no-color` with `NoColor: true` but not sure how to use `-auto-approve` and `-input=false`

Answer (score 0):

`terratest` has the ability to specify [`Options`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest@v0.28.10/modules/terraform?tab=doc#Options). This includes `NoColor`. `-auto-approve` is not included, but the included `EnvVars` can use the terraform [`TF_CLI_ARGS`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_cli_args-and-tf_cli_args_name) environment variable to specify the `-auto-approve` option.